# API design for a collection of resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api-design

In my app I have the concept of a Page and an Order. A user is able to do a POST to /orders and pass the pages that he wants to be created for that Order.

For 10 pages within the Order, they are created almost instantly. However, when that number increases (1000 pages within an Order for example), it gets slow to create all those Pages and return the ids of the just created Pages.

I need to return to the User the ids of the pages that were just created within the Order, because otherwise the user will not know which resources were created.

My question is:

- How do you deal in this kind of situations? I can limit the number of pages that can be put within an Order, but conceptually an Order can have thousdands of pages.

Comment: What is slow? The request or the database queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the database part, I suggest you use the bulk insert using the active-record import

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

For the display, you should use pagination